# Порядковый номер элемента

Tags: jquery

Есть блок в котором лежат 4 лейбла, нужно определить номер лейбла у которого есть класс 'ui-state-active'. Брать через индекс не получится. Остается вариант с .eq() только вот, код ниже выводит совсем не номер.

```
(function($){
var sl_number = '';
   $(".radio-lbl").each(function (i) {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('ui-state-active') ) { 
            sl_number = $(this).eq(); 
        }
    });
console.log(sl_number);
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: а кто вам сказал, что eq() возвращает номер?

Comment: я поэтому и задал вопрос, потому что не возвращает

Comment: Я, конечно, далеко не гуру JavaScript'a? поэтому задам элементарный вопрос - а что вам мешает использовать обычный цикл в этих целях?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sl_number = $('.radio-lbl').index($('.ui-state-active'))
```

[Доки](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 3):

А на что вам параметр `i` в функции, который обозначает счетчик?

```
(function($){
var sl_number = '';
   $(".radio-lbl").each(function (i) {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('ui-state-active') ) { 
            sl_number = i; 
        }
    });
console.log(sl_number);
})(jQuery);
```